# Pyspark DataFrame does not quote data at save

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, quotes

I am trying to save a file to hdfs using `com.databricks.spark.csv` package, but it does not quote my data, although i define it.

What i am doing wrong?

```
df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').mode('overwrite').option("header", "false").option("quote","\"").save(output_path)
```

I am calling using `--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0`

output:

> john,doo,male

expected:

> "john","doo","male"

Answer (score 0):

In Spark >= 2.X you should use the option `quoteAll`:

```
df.write \
    .format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
    .mode('overwrite') \
    .option("header", "false") \
    .option("quoteAll","true") \
    .save(output_path)
```

Comment: Can we still use `com.databricks.spark.csv` in Spark 2.x?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @desertnaut. You can indeed do `df.write.mode("overwrite").csv(mypath, sep=',')` in Spark 2.x, so it has native support and no need of using the `com.databricks.spark.csv`, but still, you can use it.